# User defined function in MATLAB / built-in function

Tags: matlab, simulink

Could anyone tell what is teta in that simulink model?
[image: simulink model]

Is that built-in function or user defined function?
REFERENCE :

[Simulation and modelling of Pico-hydro system](http://www.wseas.us/e-library/conferences/2008/corfu/control/control16.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

It **could** refer to the step function:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function

But being user-configurable and since you did not provide any context at all, it could as well be anything else.
Notably, as far as I know that label on the simulink-block is configurable - so there could be anything behing that block.

Comment: I don't understand why you refer it to step function?

Comment: Because in physics it's often denoted by a theta. As I mentioned, it was a wild guess - obviously wrong. I'm only pretty sure it's not a builting (at least I could not find theta/teta as a matlab function).